# String interpolation escape quote PITA

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

It drives me crazy that string interpolation has some special rules that disallow a straight forward translation from `a + b` style:

```
// ok
def test(f: java.io.File) = {
  val abs = f.getAbsoluteFile
  val isF = abs.isFile
  "select " + (if (isF) "file" else "folder") +"\"" + abs.getName +"\" of folder"
}

// fail
def test(f: java.io.File) = {
  val abs = f.getAbsoluteFile
  val isF = abs.isFile
  s"select ${if (isF) "file" else "folder"} \"${abs.getName}\" of folder"
}
```

And then with a lovely error message:

```
<console>:38: error: value $ is not a member of String
         s"select ${if (isF) "file" else "folder"} \"${abs.getName}\" of folder of the front window"
                                                     ^
```

What is wrong with the s-string here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you can't leave unescaped quotes in a single-quoted string, as you do when you put quotes around the words file and folder. Try it with a triple-quoted string, which allows unescaped quotes within it (it is only terminated by a second triple of quotes):

```
s"""select ${if (isF) "file" else "folder"} "${abs.getName}" of folder"""
```

Comment: I also found this as bug [SI-6476](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476). Downside of triple quotes is, IntelliJ IDEA has hickups when string ends with quotation, like `"""foo""""`. Damn...

Comment: Heh, if that were the worst criticism you could throw at IntelliJ IDEA, then it has come a long way...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love IDEA, it's just that since it is a separate compiler, it never ever adheres 100% to the spec, no matter which plugin update you have, there's always highlight bugs somewhere...

Comment: I thought eclipse IDE was getting a quick fix converter for interpolation.